# Using Migrate API, is it possible to UPDATE entities on subsequent imports?

Tags: 8, migrations, importing-exporting

I am using Migrate API with Migrate Plus, Tools and Source CSV to create Commerce Products from a CSV file. The CSV file will be updated daily where the product info (prices, stock level, etc) may change. As far as I can tell, Migrate doesn't recognize changes to the source of existing content once it's been imported.

Is there a way to re-import a file and pull changes to the file (source)

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer:

add --update to your drush command (drush mi your_migration --update)